# How can I optimize the performance of my React app when dealing with a large amount of data?

Tags: reactjs

i am building an e-commerce website that displays products in a grid format. Each product has a title, image, description, and price. The website is fetching data from an API that returns an array of 10,000 products. The products are displayed using a custom React component called "ProductCard". When the user scrolls through the products, the app becomes slow and unresponsive.

i have noticed that the performance issues are caused by the large number of product cards that are being rendered at once. i want to find a way to optimize the performance of my React app so that the user can smoothly scroll through the products without any lag.

Comment: Pagination / virtual lists / etc.

Comment: by pagination all i understand is i can fetch data part by part from api , but here all data comes at once , if i try pagination on this data will it prevent other product cards from rendering at once ? and i am not fimiliar with virtual lists , it would be helpfull if you can provide any resourse url that you may recommand .

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to optimize your react app, like code-splitting (https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) or lazy loading (https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-lazy-loading-with-react/)

Comment: actually i am specifially trying to prevent rendering  all of these product cards at once , in this senario is there any way code splitting or lazy loading can help ?

Comment: they deal with slow loading, for example, if you're using lazy loading with images, then the page will render and then the images will load.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a design problem. Curious how you finalized fetching 10000 products at once.

There are two things you can do here :

1. Use pagination to fetch 20 products at once. Fetch more item if user requests ( infinite scroll or pagination )
2. You can use [react virtual](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/) list to render the items on the Front end side. That way only the items which are shown on the view are added to DOM. So Your UI stays light weight and eliminates the crash.

Here is the example : [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-likhfv?file=src/App.js)